# I unplugged my macbook pro from the wall instead of the laptop;is it damaged?

Tags: macbook-pro

I unplugged my macbook pro from the wall instead of the computer; now the green light turns immediately orange when I plug it in; have I damaged the macbook?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean.  You unplugged the power adapter for your laptop, and now it's not working?  Why do you think this had anything to do with unplugging it?  (Aren't these designed to be unplugged?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The charger light changes color to indicate that it is charging the [Macbook Pro battery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagSafe#Features):

> LEDs on both sides show green if the computer battery is fully charged and amber or red if the battery is charging.

Comment: Thank you,Daniel;The battery is obviously charging because the color is amber...I'm a novice...thanks for your help!